# Moving files with python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am trying to write a python script that moves a file from one directory to another. I've tried two different solutions, both ending in errors.

Number one:

```
import os

os.rename('C:\users\python\nonpython\adam.spc','C:\users\python\target\adam.spc')
```

Gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Python/movefile.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.rename('C:\users\python\nonpython\adam.spc','C:\users\python\target\adam.spc')
WindowsError: [Error 123] Felaktig syntax för filnamn, katalognamn eller volymetikett
```

("Bad syntax for file name, directory name or volume label")

Number two:

```
import shutil

def move(src, dest):
    shutil.move(src, dest)

src='C:\users\python\nonpython\Adam.spc'
dest='C:\users\python\target\Adam.spc'

move(src,dest)
```

Gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Python/movefile2.py", line 9, in <module>
    move(src,dest)
  File "C:/Users/Python/movefile2.py", line 4, in move
    shutil.move(src, dest)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 301, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\users\\python\nonpython\\Adam.spc'
```

What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

**3 options to fix this:**

- Use forward slashes:

`'path/to/your/stuff'`

- Or raw strings:

`r'path\to\your\stuff'`

- Or at least escape your backslashes:

`'path\\to\\your\\stuff'`

This needs doing because `\` is a special character in strings, for indicating special characters like `\n`. Therefore that will end badly when you want to work dynamically with paths.

Answer (score 0):

try using slashes instead of backslashes - replace `\` with `/`. or use `r'C:\users\python\nonpython\adam.spc'`

Comment: What does the r mean?

Comment: raw string - https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 0):

Your directory names should have slashes instead of backslashes.

```
import os

src = 'C:/users/python/nonpython/Adam.spc'
dest = 'C:/users/python/target/Adam.spc'

os.rename(src, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your backslashes with forward slashes in the Path:

```
os.rename('C:/users/python/nonpython/adam.spc','C:/users/python/target/adam.spc')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not move a file to another directory using rename, you can rename a file using move though. Move can replace an existing file (use /y), rename can't.

You can both use slash or backslash, backslash needs to be escaped by using 2 backslashes where you need 1 and 4 backslashes where you need 2.

Your function move needs a return.